# If Then else Xpath wso2

Tags: if-statement, wso2

I have practice to validation alphabet and numeric. i was can validating both of them. but the return was true or false. with fn:matches combine with escape characters regex. can anyone help me to correct my validation.

My Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/a" name="A" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST">
        <inSequence>
            <property expression="json-eval($.OperationValueRegex.Value)" name="Value" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                <format>
                    <OperationValueRegex xmlns="">
                        <Result1>$1</Result1>
                    </OperationValueRegex>
                </format>
                <args>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="if($ctx:Value != '') then fn:tokenize($ctx:Value, ' ')[matches(., '^\d+$')]" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"/>
                </args>
            </payloadFactory>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

Expected Result : when not input was not number there was new tag xml for description error
Sample Request:

```
{
    "OperationValueRegex" : {
        "Value" : "sadasdsadasd"
    }
}
```

Result expected

```
<OperationValueRegex>
    <Result1>sadasdsadasd</Result1>
    <Status>the input not correct</Status>
</OperationValueRegex>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For This requirement, you can use wso2 [validate](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Validate+Mediator) mediator. You can use the below json schema to validate the payload. You need to save this in the registry(use the media type as application/json).

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "OperationValueRegex": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "Value": {
          "type": "number"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "Value"
      ]
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "OperationValueRegex"
  ]
}
```

Then you can use the above json schema to validate the payload using validate mediator and construct the expected payload.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="test"
       startOnLoad="true"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       transports="http,https">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property expression="json-eval($.OperationValueRegex.Value)"
                   name="Value"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <validate cache-schema="true">
            <schema key="conf:/schema/schema.json"/>
            <on-fail>
               <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                  <format>
                     <OperationValueRegex xmlns="">
                        <Result1>$1</Result1>
                        <Status>the input not correct</Status>
                     </OperationValueRegex>
                  </format>
                  <args>
                     <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:Value"/>
                  </args>
               </payloadFactory>
               <respond/>
            </on-fail>
         </validate>
         <respond/>
      </inSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```